# postgres - How to get date format from string date

Tags: python, postgresql

I am importing some data from file and every time I get different format of date. So I want to get date format by any function of postgres from database field which is char.

For example,
    `my_date`
    `-----------`
     `2018-01-30`
or
    `my_date`
    `-----------`
     `30.01.2018`

Comment: Do you really have a mixture of these two date formats in a single column?  If so, then I recommend scrubbing your data outside of Postgres, before you even import it.  If you do know the string date format for each column, I think you can handle this in Postgres easily enough.

Comment: There will be one of date format and format is not fixed so I want to get date format from field

Comment: This isn't a problem best handled in the database.  Again, I suggest exporting all your data in the same format.

Comment: PostgreSQL's date input functions are pretty flexible. Have you tried `my_date::date`?

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen I had export data in same format :)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it doesn't work for me as I want just format

Comment: The best solution would be to have a word with the creators of the source file and agree upon using only a particular format.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Thank you I had found solution

Comment: @Deval I don't understand. If you mean to say that you want the result as `text`, then you would of course use `my_date::date::text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple

to_char(mydate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')

other types of date formats :
'DD/MON/YYYY'
'DD/MON/YY'
'MON/DD/YYYY'
u can switch / with a - or .

Answer (score 0):

Python's pandas has an option to infer datetime. I have used it successfully on non-standard time formats, where regex did not work.

```
pd.to_datetime(...,...,..., infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: But I want in postgres not in python

Comment: The post is tagged with both python & postgresql. It's best to clean your data before you put it in the database. I don't know of any built-in functions that can convert multi-format VARCHAR to DATE, but you could write your own.